# When I show a gif as a ImageIcon, the screen goes white between frames

Tags: java, gif

When I put a `gif` in `JFrame` as `ImageIcon`, between frames, a white screen will shown.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Between frames of your Java Swing application, or between frames of the GIF?

Comment: between frames of my gif